# Speed up jQuery search over select element options

Tags: jquery, html, vbscript

I'm upgrading an old classic ASP application using client-side VBScript to a more modern framework using jQuery. In this instance, my jQuery replacement is noticeably slower running in IE8 than the previous VBScript. Here is the script I am replacing:

```
Function Find()
  name = Ucase(MyForm.SearchBox.value)
  For x = 0 to MyForm.ComboBox.Length - 1
    If Ucase(Left(MyForm.ComboBox.options(x).text,len(name)))=name Then
      MyForm.ComboBox.options(x).Selected = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Here is my replacement:

```
var text = $('#SearchBox').val();
$('#ComboBox option').each(function () {
  if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    $(this).prop('selected', true);
    return false;
  }
});
```

There is no delay / freeze at all running the VBScript. The user can type as fast as he wants and the search keeps up. On the same machine, with the same data, the jQuery solution has a very noticeable delay responding to text; it appears like the keyboard entry is frozen while the search is happening.

The `ComboBox` element is an HTML `select` with about 3,500 `option` elements. This method is firing on the `keyup` event of the search box.

**What optimizations can I make so that this jQuery runs as fast as the old VBScript?**

Comment: One suggestion is to declare `var $this = $(this);` and use `$this`variable instead of using `$(this)` multiple times which will make jQuery search for the object every time. But I am not sure how much it will help you in this scenario!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a binary search on the sorted options. I guess the jQuery engine is just not as efficient on IE8 vs. the VBScript engine on this type of search.

```
var searchFoo = function(text) {
    var searchFor = text.toUpperCase();
    var options = $('#ComboBox > option');

    var low = 0;
    var mid;
    var high = options.length - 1;
    var target;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = Math.ceil(low + (high - low) / 2);
        target =
          options.eq(mid).text().toUpperCase().substring(0, searchFor.length);

        if (searchFor < target) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else if (searchFor > target) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            // We found an option that matches. We want the *first* option that
            // matches, so search up through the array while they still match.
            while (mid > 0) {
                target =
                  options.eq(mid - 1).text().toUpperCase()
                         .substring(0, searchFor.length);
                if (searchFor == target) {
                    mid--;
                } else {
                    return options.eq(mid);
                }
            }
            return options.eq(mid);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, use this line and it should speed things up:

```
var t = $('#SearchBox').val().toUpperCase();

$('#ComboBox > option[value="' + t + '"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Here's my jsFiddle when testing out my code to get to this result:

http://jsfiddle.net/YE3wG/

Comment: Getting the uppercase search value outside of the loop is a good optimization; thanks! However, unless I'm missing something, your test is not the same; I am doing a case-insensitive "starts with" comparison with the text of each option.

Comment: Ohh, of course, you're 100% correct - completely forgot about that in my solution. In that case, the most I could optimize your code was the commented out solution in my jsFiddle.

Comment: Also, remember the ">" in the selector which'll save processing. And, the shorter the element names (for more than one time use) the quicker it'll be for a 3500 element loop, such as make var t = $(this).text(); etc.

Comment: If the starts with is the the only thing stopping you from using the above code you can change the jQuery Selector to '#ComboBox > option[value^="' + t + '"]' ... the main difference being the ^= inside the [] selects all attributes that start with the supplied text.  http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/